# Removing scratches just using toothpaste?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

I heard someone back in the bus said its possible to remove scratches in the body of vehicle just using the toothpaste.Is that true?

Comment: On what surface? What type of paint? metallic paint / lacquered? What brand of toothpaste?

Comment: I guess in metalic surfaces in a car

Comment: Type of paint? Base coat & Lacquer etc??

Comment: Hey solar mike,I'm not that much aware of type of paint,anyway im going to give a try tomorrow and give an update ,If Im missing any key points please feel free to reply

Comment: On a colour coat you may be lucky and it works. On a lacquer coat - if the scratch has gone through to the base coat then you will cause more damage imho.

Answer (score 3):

Toothpaste is basically calcium carbonate a coarse material like a sand paper.                  i have used it to clean the car headlamp and rear view mirror.It gets ultra clean.though I have not used it on any painted surface by myself but some articles suggest that it can remove minor scratches from paint.Refer this

> According to Ryan Dube of MakeUseOf, toothpaste is a sanding tool. It's like a lighter, softer form of sandpaper. As you gently rub toothpaste onto a slick surface, it "catches" on any imperfections that exist and softly sands them away, wearing away the uneven surface problems and polishing the surface clean.

reference https://macgyverisms.wonderhowto.com/how-to/remove-scratches-scuff-marks-your-cars-paint-job-with-toothpaste-0161471/

I think you could give it a try at a small surface of your car no harm at it.

Comment: I'll definitely give a try tomorrow and give an update

Comment: @Masterpiece.beta Whats the update ? How did it go ?